# Rails 5 Nested Form Attributes not Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok guys I have a User table that is related to a profile table, I believe I have done everything that I am suppose to do to get the nested form attributes to save however they do not save to the database. I have read the other posts and none seem to fit or the solutions do not work. To be clear I am using Rails 5 with MySQL on a Linux based system.
I have included the relevant files below

**Users Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Profiles Model**

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.create_profile
    @user.build_profile
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :user_type_id, profile_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :cell_number, :email])
    end
end
```

**Users Form Partial**

```
<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>
      <% if user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.text_field :password %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <% if params[:trainer] == "true" %>
        <%= f.label :user_type_id %>
        <%= f.text_field :user_type_id %>
        <% else %>
        Nota trainer
        <% end %>
      </div>
        <h2>Account Profile</h2>
        <%= f.fields_for :profiles do |client_profile| %>
          <%#= client_profile.inspect %>
            <div>
              <%= client_profile.label :first_name %>
              <%= client_profile.text_field :first_name %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= client_profile.label :middle_name %>
              <%= client_profile.text_field :middle_name %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= client_profile.label :last_name %>
              <%= client_profile.text_field :last_names %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= client_profile.label :email %>
              <%= client_profile.text_field :email %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= client_profile.label :phone_number %>
              <%= client_profile.text_field :phone_number %>
            </div>
            <div>
              <%= client_profile.label :cell_phone %>
              <%= client_profile.text_field :phone_number %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

**New View**

```
New User

    <%= render 'form', user: @user %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

**Params Debug Output**

```
{
"utf8"=>"✓",
"_method"=>"patch", 
"authenticity_token"=>"oZwa3K5QJRKlWGf176/fOOmrANd07KUyXUJa8Ig9CtEq+OilF73R9CzWVXwE2+K/crSFfm5p3yaeW+u2KSEF7w==",
 "user"=>{
           "username"=>"vitago", 
           "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
           "profiles"=>{
                         "first_name"=>"John", 
                         "middle_name"=>"B", 
                         "last_names"=>"Doe",            
                         "email"=>"johnbdoe@gmail.com", 
                         "phone_number"=>"1002223333"
                        }
          },
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

**Log Output in development.log**

```
   Started PATCH "/users/1" for 192.168.0.31 at 2017-03-02 01:28:22 -0500
    Cannot render console from 192.168.0.31! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
    Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {
        "utf8"=>"✓",      
     "authenticity_token"=>"GRKhJuTuytcwr4ycCBi0KiFNkmRCstPAnaP0Z8UucWZFp5JdfmosqOvIQ7WpgYUN8yHvEcmMcmYOPLX1iDUwAA==", 
        "user"=>{
        "username"=>"vitago", 
        "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
        "profiles"=>{
            "first_name"=>"John", 
            "middle_name"=>"B", 
            "last_names"=>"Doe", 
            "email"=>"johnbdoe@gmail.com", 
            "phone_number"=>"1002223333"
         }
    }, 
    "commit"=>"Update User", 
    "id"=>"1"
}
      User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
    Unpermitted parameter: profiles
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
       (0.1ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://192.168.0.51:3000/users/1
    Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


    Started GET "/users/1" for 192.168.0.31 at 2017-03-02 01:28:22 -0500
    Cannot render console from 192.168.0.31! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
    Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
      Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
      User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
      Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
      Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 29.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)


    Started GET "/users/1/edit" for 192.168.0.31 at 2017-03-02 01:28:24 -0500
    Cannot render console from 192.168.0.31! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
    Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
      Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
      User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
      Rendering users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
      Rendered users/_form.html.erb (7.1ms)
      Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (12.5ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 35.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Comment: `@user.create_profile` this line should be removed, `@user.build_profile` is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:profile` is the name of your nested model, so in your user_params try `profile_attributes` instead:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :user_type_id, profile_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :email, :phone_number, :cell_number])
end
```

Also it looks like you forgot `:email` in your nested profile params

This line in your form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profiles do |client_profile| %>
```

it should be:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile do |client_profile| %>
```

`User` `has_one` `profile`, so profile should be singular in your nested form.

UPDATE:

Both new and edit actions need to have an empty profile built in them in order for the nested form to appear:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_profile
end

# GET /users/1/edit
def edit
  @user.build_profile
end
```

Comment: Nope still not saving the data.

Comment: When i change :profiles to :profile I end up with nothing displaying for the nested attributes. Adding email to the profile_atrributes: did not effect it either way.

Comment: hm, maybe it's because you are not using the `@user` instance variable in your form_for helper:  `form_for(@user)`.  it's only a partial so i can't see the whole picture.  i could be mistaken

Comment: added the new view to my post

Comment: `@user.profile.build` should be `@user.build_profile` in your new action of the controller.  it's different syntax than `has_many`.  if that fixes it i'll update my answer

Comment: Nope same result. I had it that way once before from another post, just changed it and still did not work. This is super confusing LOL

Comment: agreed :)  Nested forms can be tricky.  I would check your server log to see what the parameters look like when you submit the form.

Comment: Will do and will report my findings in a couple hours!

Comment: Added additional information to the bottom to show log and params debug. I also formatted the output for readability!

Comment: are you testing this in your edit view?  because you will need `@user.build_profile` there as well in your edit action.  That's why your form was not showing up.  Also, again, you need `f.fields_for :profile`, not :profiles.

Comment: This is the answer that actually got it working. However the update screen was still working despite not having the **@user.build_profile** in the edit method like @Sraven suggested. I did however add it just in case. I now have the same issue with a one to many relationship that I am trying to solve and if I cannot I will create another post for it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have few changes to make, some are already given in @Ren's answer,

**1)**  New action, `@user.create_profile` not needed.

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_profile
end
```

**2)**  `<%= form_for(user) do |f| %>` should be, **`<%= form_for @user do |f| %>`**

**3)**  `<%= f.fields_for :profiles do |client_profile| %>` should be, **`<%= f.fields_for :profile do |client_profile| %>`**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <% if user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
                    <% user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                    <li><%= message %></li>
                    <% end %>
            </ul>
       </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <% if params[:trainer] == "true" %>
    <%= f.label :user_type_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_type_id %>
    <% else %>
    Nota trainer
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <h2>Account Profile</h2>
    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |client_profile| %>
        <%#= client_profile.inspect %>
        <div>
            <%= client_profile.label :first_name %>
            <%= client_profile.text_field :first_name %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= client_profile.label :middle_name %>
            <%= client_profile.text_field :middle_name %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= client_profile.label :last_name %>
            <%= client_profile.text_field :last_names %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= client_profile.label :email %>
            <%= client_profile.text_field :email %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= client_profile.label :phone_number %>
            <%= client_profile.text_field :phone_number %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= client_profile.label :cell_phone %>
            <%= client_profile.text_field :phone_number %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @BetaZed Software Solutions, checked my answer?

Comment: This added some extra's however the addition to the edit method in the controller did not make a difference. It worked regardless whether **@user.build_profile** was in the edit method or not. I added it to be safe however it did not appear to effect things.